# How to take snapshot of a Document Files getting from Server

Tags: ios, pdf, document

All,
We have a requirement for displaying images, Documents (PDF,doc,docx,xl etc..), If it is a image we can show the thumbnail, For Documents can we take snapshot and display it. Is it possible. For example if you see the new WhatsApp document share feature, When we share PDF or some file we are getting image of the document then when we click on it is showing complete data, How can we get it. Please let me know

Thanks

Comment: may it help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10919075/image-of-the-first-pdf-page-ios-sdk

Comment: you can use the webview to get the thumbnail of the documents. see the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8475125/is-it-possibile-get-thumbail-image-from-doc-or-xls-document